# How to log all Axios external http requests in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, nestjs

I want to be able to log each axios request with full url, headers, etc but currently didn't find a way to do so.

What I did achieve so far is to writhe an Http Interceptor based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52419105/415078_consuming:false)

```
export class HttpLoggerInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    call$: Observable<any>,
  ): Observable<any> {
    return call$.pipe(
      map(data => {
        // pipe call to add / modify header(s) after remote method
        const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        return data;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I browse through the objects `req` and `context` props on debug but could not see Asios request url, etc. Unless I missed that.

My controller route (`api/data` in that case) have N number of http external calls taking place but interceptor intercepts only controller controller call not Axios calls.

Any thoughts?

That is `context` object:

```
args:Array(2) [IncomingMessage, ServerResponse]
constructorRef:class AppController { … }
getRequest:() => …
getResponse:() => …
handler:data() { … }
__proto__:Object {constructor: , getClass: , getHandler: , …}
```

that is `req`:

```
_dumped:false
_events:Object {}
_eventsCount:0
_maxListeners:undefined
_parsedOriginalUrl:Url {protocol: null, slashes: null, auth: null, …}
_parsedUrl:Url {protocol: null, slashes: null, auth: null, …}
_readableState:ReadableState {objectMode: false, highWaterMark: 16384, buffer: BufferList, …}
baseUrl:""
body:Object {}
client:Socket {connecting: false, _hadError: false, _handle: TCP, …}
complete:true
connection:Socket {connecting: false, _hadError: false, _handle: TCP, …}
destroyed:false
fresh:false
headers:Object {accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", user-agent: "axios/0.18.0", host: "localhost:3000", …}
host:"localhost"
hostname:"localhost"
httpVersion:"1.1"
httpVersionMajor:1
httpVersionMinor:1
ip:"::ffff:127.0.0.1"
ips:Array(0)
method:"GET"
next:function next(err) { … }
originalUrl:"/api/data"
params:Object {}
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
path:"/api/data"
protocol:"http"
query:Object {}
rawHeaders:Array(8) ["Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*", "User-Agent", …]
rawTrailers:Array(0) []
readable:true
readableBuffer:BufferList
readableFlowing:null
readableHighWaterMark:16384
readableLength:0
res:ServerResponse {_events: Object, _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: undefined, …}
route:Route {path: "/api/data", stack: Array(1), methods: Object}
secure:false
socket:Socket {connecting: false, _hadError: false, _handle: TCP, …}
stale:true
statusCode:null
statusMessage:null
subdomains:Array(0)
trailers:Object {}
upgrade:false
url:"/api/data"
xhr:false
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nest.js-Interceptors only process the request handled by your controller and the response going out. If you make http requests with Axios while you handle a controller request, they won't be processed by an interceptor.

---

### Axios Interceptor

The `HttpService` exposes its `axios` instance directly via `get axiosRef()`. With it, you can add an [`axios interceptor`](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors):

```
this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use(config => { /*...*/ return config })
```

You can for example do that in the [`onModuleInit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484892/4694994) of your `AppModule`.

---

### Delegate to Facade

As an alternative, you can create an `HttpService` facade, that logs the request and delegates all calls to the built-in `HttpService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpService {
  private logger: Logger = new Logger(MyHttpService.name);

  constructor (private httpService: HttpService) {}
  
  public get<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Observable<AxiosResponse<T>> {
    this.logger.log({url, config});
    return this.httpService.get(url, config)
       .pipe(tap(response => this.logger.log(response)));
  }

  // ... all the other methods you need.

}
```

You can create your own `LoggingHttpModule` that imports the built-in `HttpModule` and exports your `MyHttpService`.

Comment: which approach would you recommend? Seems like the second approach involves a bit more code. If you go with the  `Axios Interceptor` approach where would you stick the `this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use(config => console.log(config));` code ? `>You can for example do that in the onModuleInit() of your AppModule` - would you give a bit more background on that?

Comment: Have a look at this answer's second part where `OnModuleInit` is explained. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484892/4694994 And yes, I would recommend using the axios Interceptor solution.

Comment: In typescript version of NestJS I was required to use slightly altered interceptor `this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use((config: AxiosRequestConfig) => { console.log(config); return config; });`

Comment: Just trying to implement axios interceptor, having an issue with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869611/nestjs-server-internal-error-when-using-axios-interceptors

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i @types/morgan

npm i morgan
```

then

```
import * as morgan from 'morgan';

export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(morgan('combined'))
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a centralised solution with no extra library, this is how I added my bearer token to all external api calls, with a log when it happens:

```
@Injectable()
export class IdkAxiosInterceptor implements OnModuleInit {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(IdkAxiosInterceptor.name);
  private token = undefined;

  constructor(
    @Inject(HttpService)
    private httpService: HttpService,
    @Inject(TokenExchangeService)
    private tokenExchangeService: TokenExchangeService,
  ) {
    this.refreshToken();
  }

  onModuleInit(): any {
    const { axiosRef: axios } = this.httpService;

    axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      return this.onRequest(config);
    }, Promise.reject);
  }

  onRequest(config) {
    this.logger.log('external call for ' + config.url);
    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${this.token}`;

    return config;
  }

  @Cron(EVERY_50_MINUTES)
  refreshToken() {
    this.tokenExchangeService.getAccessToken(Environment.PRODUCTION).subscribe(({ access_token }) => {
      this.token = access_token;
    });
  }
}
```

Now you just need to add it to your main module as a provider and thats it.

If you want I can post the test for it :D