# How to log the http sending headers in nestjs

Tags: http, http-headers, nestjs

I am new to nestjs, having trouble when trying to log the http sending request headers.

```
{ "timestamp":"2022-08-01T22:16:08.909Z","AppId":"","AppName":this.appId,"fsreqid":"testfsreqid","level":"debug", "message":"Option resolved successfully.","rest":[
{
  headers: {
    fsreqid: 'testfsreqid',
    AppName: 'NewApp',
    AppId: 'APP123'
  },
```

Comment: You could try the suggestions in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54229131/how-to-log-all-axios-external-http-requests-in-nestjs